# Quickly Update Static Content on WildFly Server

Tags: wildfly

I have web application that is deployed to a local WildFly server. I am currently working on the front-end and am having troubles testing the data calls. All of my data gathering is done via AJAX and thus requires that I be on an actual server to silence any Cross-Site issues. This isn't a problem, but it is very time-consuming to re-deploy the entire application just to tweak a line of javascript.

I have successfully been able to deploy an exploded war. However, this forces a re-deploy when I saved the file. Is there a way for me to have it automatically update static content quickly without re-deploying?

Comment: I have exact the same problem. I'm new to wildfly and Java Web development, but quite experienced in using frontend automation tools like gulp. It would be awesome to have livereload working in wildfly environment, just as I got used to :)

Comment: What did you end up doing here? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this CORSFilter I think I found
[here](https://github.com/Trunkplatform/lazybones-dropwizard-turbo/blob/master/templates/dropwizard-turbo/src/main/java/packageName/jersey/CORSFilter.java). There are plenty around.

This will add `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers to responses which in turn prevents the client from rejecting the reply as it would otherwise do for security reasons.

I have it included in my web app (for now), running on `http://localhost:8080`
and I can then run my grunt/gulp/node server on
`http://localhost:8000` on the same machine w/ `livereload` ''as
usual'' doing requests between the servers.

I am a backend architect and I haven't done much frontend so there
might be better sollutions around; this is how I solved it today.

The `CORSFilter`:

```
@Singleton
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext, final ContainerResponseContext cres)
        throws IOException {
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the answer you hoped for; but you another way is to use the right front-end development tools. For example: Webpack (http://webpack.github.io/) to build and test your front-end while mocking your REST-backend. That way you can also easily unit test your JavaScript front-end.